# Trouble with understanding why a variable isn't being updated

Tags: c#, multithreading, photon

I'm a novice programmer and am having trouble understanding why this isn't working. 
I have a "ConnectedClientList" class:

```
public class ConnectedClientList
{
    static readonly object _lock = new object();
    public static IList<ClientPeer> ConnectedClientPeers;

    static ConnectedClientList()
    {
         ConnectedClientPeers = new List<ClientPeer>();
    }


    public static IList<ClientPeer> GetClientPeers()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return ConnectedClientPeers;
        }

    }

    public static void AddClientPeerToConnectedList(ClientPeer client)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            ConnectedClientPeers.Add(client);
        }                
    }

    public void RemoveClientPeerFromConnectedList(ClientPeer client)
    {
        ConnectedClientPeers.Remove(client);
    }
}
```

I have this in another class:

```
ClientPeer clientPeer = new ClientPeer(request, Logger, _clientHandlerRegistry);

ConnectedClientList.AddClientPeerToConnectedList(clientPeer);
Logger.InfoFormat("Added clientpeer to list. Count is now: {0}", ConnectedClientList.ConnectedClientPeers.Count);
```

And then finally I have this:

```
public CharacterUpdateEventHandler(ILogger logger)
    {
        Logger = logger;
        IFiber testFiber = new ThreadFiber();
        testFiber.Start();
        testFiber.ScheduleOnInterval(SendUpdateEventToClients, 1000, 5000);
    }

    public void SendUpdateEventToClients()
    {
        if(ConnectedClientList.GetClientPeers() != null)
            Logger.InfoFormat("# of connected client peers: {0}", ConnectedClientList.GetClientPeers().Count);
        else
        {
            Logger.InfoFormat("ConnectedClientPeers is null");
        }
    }
```

I am trying to build a server using Exitgame's Photon Server. When I first create the clientpeer and then add it to the "ConnectedClientPeers" I immediately have debug info saying that the "ConnectedClientPeers" list does in fact now have a count of 1.

The thread I'm running seems to be repeating the "SendUpdateEventToClients" just fine, but the debug message in that function always says that my "ConnectedClientPeers" list has a count of 0.

I'm sure it's probably something simple I'm not aware of, but I haven't had any luck finding a solution for the passed couple of days. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

-Jarryd

--Edit--

I updated the class to make the entire class static, but still have the same problem.

```
public static class ConnectedClientList
{
    static readonly object _lock = new object();
    public static readonly IList<ClientPeer> ConnectedClientPeers;

    static ConnectedClientList()
    {
         ConnectedClientPeers = new List<ClientPeer>();
    }


    public static IList<ClientPeer> GetClientPeers()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            return ConnectedClientPeers;
        }

    }

    public static void AddClientPeerToConnectedList(ClientPeer client)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            ConnectedClientPeers.Add(client);
        }                
    }

    public static void RemoveClientPeerFromConnectedList(ClientPeer client)
    {
        ConnectedClientPeers.Remove(client);
    }
}
```

My debug log:
    2016-08-08 14:27:21,771 [ThreadFiber-1]  INFO [     CharacterUpdateEventHandler][   55] [(null)] - # of connected client peers: 0

2016-08-08 14:27:23,428 [ThreadFiber-2]  INFO [     CharacterUpdateEventHandler][   55] [(null)] - # of connected client peers: 0

2016-08-08 14:27:26,771 [ThreadFiber-1]  INFO [     CharacterUpdateEventHandler][   55] [(null)] - # of connected client peers: 0

2016-08-08 14:27:28,443 [ThreadFiber-2]  INFO [     CharacterUpdateEventHandler][   55] [(null)] - # of connected client peers: 0

2016-08-08 14:27:31,774 [ThreadFiber-1]  INFO [     CharacterUpdateEventHandler][   55] [(null)] - # of connected client peers: 0

2016-08-08 14:27:33,453 [ThreadFiber-2]  INFO [     CharacterUpdateEventHandler][   55] [(null)] - # of connected client peers: 0

2016-08-08 14:27:36,787 [ThreadFiber-1]  INFO [     CharacterUpdateEventHandler][   55] [(null)] - # of connected client peers: 0

2016-08-08 14:27:38,465 [ThreadFiber-2]  INFO [     CharacterUpdateEventHandler][   55] [(null)] - # of connected client peers: 0

Comment: In the other class where you call AddClientPeerToConnectedList are you sure that it is referencing the same ConnectedClientList object, or did you new up another one?

Comment: That's what I thought the problem might have been as well which is why I ended up making the variable static. Or is that not how static works? Everything related I have posted above, I didn't leave anything out. I initially had the whole class as static, but didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I made the entire class static, but that doesn't seems to make a difference. I updated my initial post and added the static class at the bottom as well as a small portion of my debug log. The log just repeats every 5 seconds with the same thing.

Comment: I feel like something's missing here.  Make the `ConnectedClientPeers` field `readonly` to ensure that you're not accidentally assigning it a new list repeatedly somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Ok I made the field readonly and edited my original post to reflect that. I am still have the same problem. My initial debug line says that I have a count of 1(right after it's added), but the thread loop still just says the same, 0.

Comment: Because you seem to be using multiple threads you may want to try setting break points in each method to make sure the code is executing in the sequence that you think

Comment: My knowledge on threading is very limited. I did notice it mentioning thread 1 and 2 in the log. I'm not sure why that is as I have posted the code above that I used to create/start the thread. I have also restarted photon a couple of times in order to make sure the threads weren't still running from earlier.

Comment: Are we viewing code from a single application?  Or are we looking at some code from a server application and some code from a client application?  (i.e., do you have two exes running -- a client and a server?)

Comment: I have a server running via Photon, that's where the debug log is from. Then I have a completely separate Unity3d application that connects as the client. It only communicates with the server via requests, so there's nothing it can be doing to alter this variable.

Comment: Ran a test creating my own non-static class with a static list and static methods to add items to the list and another static method get the list count. Created an instance of this class and call the method to add multiple times. Once I call the static method to get the count, it contains accurate data. I don't believe it's an issue with the instance of the object or anything like that. No idea what else the issue could be... perhaps something with how you're locking the list?

Comment: I was able to get this code to work, so either object is being recreated or peer being removed

Comment: BTW: your `GetClientPeers` function looks dangerous - you should return a copy of your list to be threadsafe. You simply return the reference.

Comment: Ok so there must be something I'm doing. I'm happy that the code here seems to at least be ruled out. Thanks Heinzbeinz, I'll change that. I'm still very much a novice and am learning what's a good idea and what isn't.

Comment: As GreatJobBob assumed it might be that your peer is already disconnected. we can not say this, because we do not know how do you manage CharacterUpdateEventHandler instances.

also we would not recommend you use ThreadFiber in manner you use it. use PoolFiber.
Introduce ides for CharacterUpdateEventHandler and log them out, so that you will see what is going one better.

Add logging from ClientPeer.OnDisconnect. be as versbose as possible, that you will find error faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to post code in a comment, this much of your code seems fine

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace ConsoleApplication6
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ClientPeer clientPeer = new ClientPeer();
                clientPeer.MyProperty = 5;
                ConnectedClientList.AddClientPeerToConnectedList(clientPeer);
                Console.WriteLine(ConnectedClientList.ConnectedClientPeers.Count.ToString());

                ConnectedClientList.AddClientPeerToConnectedList(clientPeer);
                Console.WriteLine(ConnectedClientList.ConnectedClientPeers.Count.ToString());


                clientPeer = new ClientPeer();
                ConnectedClientList.AddClientPeerToConnectedList(clientPeer);
                Console.WriteLine(ConnectedClientList.ConnectedClientPeers.Count.ToString());

            }

            public class ClientPeer
            {

                public int MyProperty { get; set; }

            }

            public static class ConnectedClientList
            {
                static readonly object _lock = new object();
                public static IList<ClientPeer> ConnectedClientPeers;

                static ConnectedClientList()
                {
                    ConnectedClientPeers = new List<ClientPeer>();
                }


                public static IList<ClientPeer> GetClientPeers()
                {
                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                        return ConnectedClientPeers;
                    }

                }

                public static void AddClientPeerToConnectedList(ClientPeer client)
                {
                    lock (_lock)
                    {
                        ConnectedClientPeers.Add(client);
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

So this just adds 3 peers and displays the count and shows that there are indeed 3

Comment: Thanks for taking the time GreatJobBob. I think, keyword is think, that my logic is okay. There must be something simple that I'm overlooking. Perhaps how photon's threading works, maybe it's a little different to normal threading?